# How to replace ".then" from Angular 2.x in Angular 4.x

Tags: angular

I have an Angular project in version 2.x and I want to update it to version 4.x.

```
 loginUser(): void {
    console.log("login.component.loginUser called");

    this.loginService.getTokenInfo(this.userCredentials.userName, this.userCredentials.password)
      .then(tokenInfo => this.tokenInfo = tokenInfo)
      .then(tokenInfo => myGlobals.authToken = tokenInfo.token)
      .then(() => {
        this.redirectToFuPage();
      });
  }
```

How do I change this to work for version 4.x?

My service method is as follows.

```
getTokenInfo(userName: string, password: string): Promise<TokenInfo> {
    console.log("login.service.getTokenInfo called");
    this.credentials = JSON.stringify({userName: userName, password: password});

    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, this.credentials, this.options)
               .toPromise()
               .then(res => res.json() as TokenInfo)
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

property then does not exist on observable.

It was working for me before.

Comment: `then` allows you to subscribe to a call back on a `Promise` which is what `getTokenInfo` is probably returning. It has nothing to do with Angular2 / Angular4. What prompted you to think that? Do you get an error in your `loginService` method or in the calling code? As it stands now your question does not make sense.

Comment: I get error "property 'then' does not exist on observable" error in the loginUser() method

Comment: Then you need to replace `then` with `subscribe` because, just like the error states, the return type is an `observable` and not a `Promise`. Look at the examples / demos / documentation / etc from the [angular site](https://angular.io).

Answer (score 0):

Replacing "then" with "map" when I return a Observable and replacing "then" with "subscribe" once I got the observable fixed the issue.

```
getTokenInfo(userName: string, password: string): Observable<TokenInfo> {
    this.credentials = JSON.stringify({userName: userName, password: password});

    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, this.credentials, this.options)
               .map(res => res.json() as TokenInfo)
}
```

And here is the loginUser() method

```
loginUser(): void {
    this.loginService.getTokenInfo(this.user.userName, this.user.password)
        .subscribe(response => {
           this.tokenInfo = response;
           myGlobals.authToken = this.tokenInfo.token;
           this.redirectToFuPage();
        })
}
```